# How do I switch my fork to a different Github branch?

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

I made fork a branch of a Github repository. I made changes to my fork.

A new branch was added to the repository. I want to merge the changes from the new branch to my fork, preserving my changes to my fork.

I don't own the original repository.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

#add the remote to your fork.

git remote add upstream https:/github.com/whoever/whatever.git

#update your personal fork while keeping changes (swap master with the branch you want).

git pull upstream master --rebase --autostash

This should add the remote repository to your git repo (your fork) and then you tell it to fetch the changes from that branch and add your own changes on top.